# Should I write my stipend income while filing ITR 1 for TDS-2 (India)

Tags: income-tax, india

I am new to income tax stuff. I worked as an intern in some company which deducted TDS (Tax Deducted at Source) on my stipend under section `194J` (written on my `Form 16A` certificate). Now I want to file Income Tax Return (`ITR 1`) for the same. I am filing it online using [official government website](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in).

The website shows my TDS details in `Tax Details` under section `Sch-TDS 2 - Details of Tax Deducted at source form income OTHER THAN Salary`. It has all the necessary details.

My Question is : Do I need to give stipend details manually in income section (maybe income from other sources section) of ITR 1 while filing it online since it is zero there?

OR

Just filing without entering any income would be fine since all the necessary details is already available in my form in TDS section.

PS: I only earned stipend (which is way below to be taxable) and no other income!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the stipend as income from other sources.

If this is the only income you should get a refund.

Comment: So even though my `stipend amount` and `TDS amount` both are showing in TDS-2 Section I need to enter `stipend amount` again in my `income from other sources `section. Is that right?

Comment: And what should be my description for `income from other sources`?

Comment: @Kartoos yes. You need to enter the amount of stipend in income from other sources and mention as stipend

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was looking for this information on google but couldn't find. Stack Exchange is awesome! :)